# How to store too large binary value in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have got a too large binary value.

```
 value1 : 2 ^ 300,000.
 value2 : 2 ^ 300,000.
```

I'd like to do 'and calculation' of value1 and value2.

First of all, how to store a value1 and value2? (int, float, double...  ???)

```
 int value1 = 2 ^ 300000;
```

Is this correct?

Does this way completly store a value?

context for using) 
I have two arrays which has 300,000 elements.

```
eg) array1 @ [@ "apple", @ "banana", @ "iphone", @ "TV", @ "clock" .... <= it has 300, 000.
    array2 @ [@ "fruit", @ "fruit", @ "electric", @ "electric", @ "electric" ....] <= also has 300,000.
```

display prefered thing to binary : 1,1,0,0,1 ... 
display prefered kind  to binary : 1,1,0,0,0 ...

result of calculating 'and' of array1 & array2 : 1,1,0,0,0 ... 
I like "apple" and "banana" of fruit.

Reason of using binary calculating are expected to be faster than other way.

Comment: Can you provide the context of the problem? Those numbers are insanely enormous.

Comment: well the OP was honest: they're **too** large

Comment: Ya, waaaaaay too large. I think he has to roll his own class to do the calculation, or this is just going to be really painful, over 90000 digits, it will need to do 90000^2 multiplications. That's going to be really slow.

Comment: Will base always be 2?

Comment: @Kirsteins also my question, but the stuff becomes quite ugly and complicated with things like: `2^300 - 2^20`, and this will require some thinking. We need the op to come back.

Comment: @ShaneHsu For the base of 2 all power in binary would be "1" followed by exponent times "0". So in this case "1" followed by 300000 "0".

Comment: @Kirsteins Yes, I see your point with binary format, but, things are complicated if he wants output frequently (AFAIK). We need op the come back, it's his problem, and I don't like to guess too much. (Maybe I'm wrong as he has the words "Binary Format" in the title.

Comment: But our general idea is the same, roll your own class. LOL

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that you are not using Objective-C classes, but Plain Old Datatype, a.k.a. POD.

That large value far exceeds the limit of integers, even 64-bit unsigned ints. I am not a math wiz, so I'm not sure if that will fit in a double but that doesn't matter because with floating-point, you loses precision. ([Link to WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E300000&dataset=) for the exact value that definitely won't fit.)

What you want is probably `NSDecimalNumber` which provide up to 38 digit precision, that's what's built into the library, if you need further precision, you can write your own class, or check out libraries like [GMP](http://gmplib.org).

There's a good question and answer about `NSDecimalNumber` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333755/nsnumber-calculations-precision).

UPDATE: As Craig mentioned in the comment, you may want to roll your own class to speed up the calculation. Libraries like GMP are general purpose, and will do the calculation in a way that's so safe that it sometimes are wasting your time as the calculation you want to do can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the `^` operator is not a power operator, but a [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).

So `2 ^ 300000` actually produces `300002`.

Secondly you can use [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), a subclass of `NSNumber`, which according to the documentation

> provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127

Comment: More precisely it's a bitwise XOR.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri absolutely right, thank you.

Comment: I don't think that NSDecimalNumber is enough to store a such a big bitmask. And it is missing methods to check individual bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 300 000 objects, have you considered to use a database, e.g. Core Data? Instead of a very large bit mask, maybe it would be easier to do the same by a single database (Core Data) request.

To answer your specific question, a C-array of integers would be probably the best solution:

```
const NUM_OBJECTS = 300000;
//8 * sizeof(int) bits per an int
int* mask = malloc((size_t) ceilf(NUM_OBJECTS / (sizeof(int) * 8.0f));
```